# Retrieve inputs, display randomized outputs

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on getting my PHP skillset up by creating a project using Laravel. It is going pretty well, until I have stumped myself.

The application is very simple. I start by getting a number of people

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'who')) }}
{{ Form::select('number', array(
    "2" => 2,
    "4" => 4,
    "6" => 6,
    "8" => 8,
    "10" => 10,
    "12" => 12
)) }}
{{ Form::submit('Click Me!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then, I generate inputs for an individuals name:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'matches')) }}
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < $number; $i++) { 
    echo Form::text('name');
}
?>  
{{ Form::submit('Last Step') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now, I just want to take the names, and output them using rand() matching them together in groups of 2. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What do you need to be random? I don't get it.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as right if it is. If not, say why or write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a PHP question than a Laravel question. If I understand, you have an array of names and you want to group them by two randomly, right ? You can do this :

```
shuffle($names);
for ($i=0;$i<count($names);$i=$i+2) {
    echo $name[$i] . ' and ' . $name[$i+1] . '<br>'
}
```

Or something like that. The key of my answer is the shuffle method (http://php.net/shuffle). You can "sort randomly" your array of name and then group the names by two in the order of this array.